# Publishing to github pages without versioning artifacts?

Tags: sass, artifacts, github-pages

Is there a way to publish to the `gh-pages` branch of a project *without* versioning generated css/js in that branch?

For example, [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/neat/commits/gh-pages/css/desktop.css) is the `gh-pages` branch version history of a generated css file, `desktop.css`. It seems that every time the scss files are changed and committed, the `desktop.css` file is also regenerated *and* committed. That seems unnecessary to store.

I am thinking of the parallel in projects that use css preprocessors like Sass or Javascript bundlers.  We typically don't version the generated code since it just repeats data we already have (the precompiled/prebundled code). If we wanted to go back to an earlier version, we would restore an older version of the Sass, for example, and regenerate the css from there. The same should be said for regenerating an earlier version of a gh-pages page, no? Also there's the issue of unnecessary artifacts and bloat to the repository from these generated files.

Is there a workaround that can have the building of the code happen *without* versioning generated css/js? One possibility I thought was about purging and re-branching the `gh-pages` branch each time I need to regenerate but that seems extreme. I sometimes wonder if Github should offer `gh-pages` as a *tag* as well as a branch so that we can move that tag to point to a different commit whenever we need Travis CI or what have you to regenerate.

How are others addressing this? Or is it just not a big deal?

**Update Thu Dec 18 19:28:16 EST 2014**

David gave a nice answer below that is Jekyll specific, demonstrating a [jekyll site with just scss](https://github.com/djacquel/JekyllDoc) but whose [hosted github page](http://jekyll.pygmeeweb.com/) was built with generated css.  It seems the magic is in the _config.yml file. While I like the answer (and upvoted it), it does not address the general case.

For now I think I will go with a periodic git purge approach. I will deploy to the `gh-pages` branch, letting it version the generated css/js. Then every once in a while, if i feel the repo has gotten too bloated, I will just empty the branch with `git filter-branch` commands as [explained by Github](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/) or just delete it locally and remotely and recreate it. That way, I get the flexibility of using whatever static site generator I want, adjusting and generating as much as I need, and keeping repo size manageable. At the price of an extra few steps.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) the static site generator [supported by Github page](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/).
Natively use sass and version only source files.
Clean !

Comment: This addresses the _generation_ of the pages (of which there are many good static site generators, like Jekyl). But how does it address Github versioning the generated artifacts when you deploy the generated results?

Comment: With Jekyll you can only deploy sources and Github takes care of the generation. Give it a try, it takes 10 minutes, and you will love it.

Comment: Part of "Github takes care of the generation" seems that it versions the artifacts. Hence my question of how to avoid that. I don't think the static site generating software (i.e. Jekyll) affects this one way or the other.

Comment: With basic use of Jekyll on gh-pages generated code is not versioned. You don't even see it.

Comment: Can you post a github repository example showing that the generated css or js code is not versioned in the ```gh-pages``` branch?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67256/discussion-between-david-jacquel-and-yuvilio).

Comment: From discussion, the Github pages hosted side of David's example is http://jekyll.pygmeeweb.com/ .

Answer (score 0):

You could add the generated files (*.css for example) to .gitignore so that even if they are created, they aren't synced to Github. But when a visitor comes to your page, their browser needs the generated .CSS files, so you really do need to publish them somehow.

Think about the opposite scenario - where git history showed .scss changes without any updates to the compiled .css. That would probably be confusing to any developer who knows that the CSS is supposed to compile from Sass; and they might start looking around for something broken in the compilation process.

Comment: Your first point illustrates my dillema well, @KatieK. I want to ```gitignore``` the generated CSS but doing so makes it not show up on github.io hosted site. 

I hear your point on getting quick answers on how the css changed as a reason to version it. But looking at the scss+sourcemaps might provide a similar if not as direct answer. It's an effort tradeoff, granted. I'd rather that and no bulky generated css/js diffs stored. David just posted an example Jekyll repo that _just_ has the scss and github figures out from the _config.yml how to generate the css.  I'm going to play with that.